# Font display: single letter corrupted (temporarily)

Tags: firefox, fonts

Certain letters (but not always the same) are (temporarily) corrupted (see below, in Mozilla Firefox 35.0.1--not sure whether in other programmes), but usually 'fixed' with selecting the letter, or minimising & restoring window.

Any ideas?

[image: Corrupted letter]

My system:
• Lenovo B50-35
• Processor: AMD A10-7800 Processor( 3.50GHz 2133MHz 4MB)
• Operating system: Ubuntu 14.10
• Display type: 23.8" All In One with Multi-touch function 1920x1080
• System Graphics: AMD Radeon R7 A260 2GB

Answer (score 0):

Does it occur only for firefox, then it must be firefox related issue.
Or, did any update to any other software (excluding firefox)/or your Linux system cause this behavior? 

If yes, is your computer supporting additional languages (more than one)? 

If recent software update is not the issue, it is likely issue with your graphics card or drivers. In some cases, it could be the RAM acting up.